# R: using ifelse statement to check if column exists, then perform calculation

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to create a function that first looks to see if a column exists, then if that column exists, perform a calculation, and if not, then keep the original variable.

Here is some data and the approach I was thinking:

```
thisdata <-  data.frame(vara = seq(from = 1, to = 20, by = 2)
                     ,varb = seq(from = 1, to = 20, by = 1))

thisdata$varc <- with(thisdata, ifelse("vard" %in% colnames(thisdata), vara - vard, vara))
```

So obviously 'vard' is not in the dataframe, however I don't get the original 'vara' variable back for my new variable (only '1'). Of course, I might have another dataframe with the 'vard' variable.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the vectorized form of `if` in this case.  Try using

```
thisdata$varc <- with(thisdata, if ("vard" %in% colnames(thisdata)) vara - vard else vara)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one , base on your effort .

```
thisdata$varc <- with(thisdata,ifelse(rep("vara" %in% colnames(thisdata),dim(thisdata)[1]), vara - varb, vara))
```

I think this link also help :https://www.programiz.com/r-programming/ifelse-function

`ifelse`:The return value is a vector with the ***same length*** as `test_expression`.(`length("vara" %in% colnames(thisdata))`=1, this why you got all 1 (1st value of `vara`)in your original attempted)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you want to use `ifelse`? I prefer using `if` when trying to do something complicated, but that's just my preference.

```
thisdata$varc <- if("vard" %in% names(thisdata)) {
  thisdata$vara - thisdata$vard
} else {
  thisdata$vara
}
```